# From which scripture are these shlokas?

Tags: scripture, identification-request, shloka

From which scripture are these shlokas from?

> स्थितस् तत्र जना यूका इव सीमन्त-संस्थिताः ॥ This earth here is the
> body of a giant living being, self-supported in empty space. On that
> are situated the people like lice dwelling in the hair.
>
> पक्षी स्वभाव-वशतो यत्र तिष्ठति खे स्वयम् । तत्र भूमेः स्थितौ शङ्का
> केयं मूढेषु जृम्भते ॥ As a bird by the force of its own nature stands
> in space, the earth to is situated (in space], why does a doubt
> (regarding this) yawn among idiots?
>
> कढ़काख्यं यथा रत्नं वस्तु स्वं प्रति कर्षति । तथा पृथ्वी वस्तुजातं
> स्वभावे कैव चोदना ॥ Just as the amber gem attracts objects towards
> itself, Why indeed, so too the earth by nature attracts all objects.
>
> पिपीलिकानां न्यायेन जनाः पृथ्व्यां व्यवस्थिताः । परितः पात-शङ्कान न
> कार्येषां तथा स्थितेः ॥ In the manner of ants son a ball, the beings
> are stationed on the earth. Held by this force all around they have no
> risk of falling off from here.

Comment: Śiṣyadhīvṛddhidatantra of Lalla, an 8th century astronomical treatise.

Comment: @Apastamba_01 if you know exact chapters, you can answer it

Comment: I think it's from one of the works of Bhaskara @Lokesh ... the famous Kashmiri Acharya. Atleast [this blog](https://vishvasa.github.io/jyotiSham/history/heliocentrism/?transliteration_target=assamese) says so.

Comment: @Vivikta I got the shlokas from there only. Unfortuantely the author of blog doesn't know the scripture from which it is taken.

Comment: It might be found in his work - Siddhanta Shiromani, in the Chapter Goladhyaya, or in the work Surya Siddhant.

Comment: @Savitr̥ I couldn't find it in Śiṣyadhīvṛddhidatantra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long search, I finally came to know that its from चित्तानुबोध, दशमाध्यायः by राजानक-भास्कराकण्ठ.

It can be accessed here - https://archive.org/details/UFmz_chittanubodha-shastram-by-bhaskara-kantha-edited-by-sushma-pandey-published-by-t/page/n271/mode/2up

BTW, this publication has quite a few errors. Following is the manuscript of it.

[image]